# Why is Emacsclient opening and immediately closing?

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-mavericks

So, when I invoke emacsclient as `emacsclient -a "" <file_name>`, it opens and in the blink of an eye closes!

I tried options like -n -c etc. No use. I even tried using the emacsclient binary from Aquamacs to no avail.

I'm on a Mac with zsh. Is this a known issue? Am I missing something (like some setting)?

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you running? I've seen a lot of Mac users still using Emacs 22 (which is something like seven years old) whereas the `--daemon` and `-a` arguments were introduced in Emacs 23. Obligatory link to http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: @phils I'm using emacs 24.3.1. I also have emacs for mac and aquamacs. All of them exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: I suggest killing all running instances of Emacs (does OSX have `pgrep` and `pkill` ?), then running `emacs -Q --daemon` and finally `emacsclient <file_name>` to verify whether the basic daemon/client functionality works. I would also verify `emacs --version` and `emacsclient --version` to ensure each is the version you believe it to be.

Comment: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/5978  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56871/emacs-daemon-crashing-after-closing-emacsclient-c